# NGINX QUIC Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse, quic, http3

I’am  testing NGINX quit/http3 implementation from the branch https://hg.nginx.org/nginx-quic.

I would like to enable reverse proxy for QUIC protocol in NGINX and it’s looks like is not worked properly. There is my configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

error_log /dev/stdout info;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
    upstream quic_upstreams {
        server myserver:443;
    }

    #Forwarding through QUIC
    server {
        listen 443 quic reuseport;
        proxy_pass quic_upstreams;

        ssl_certificate     certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/key.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;
        ssl_alpn h3 h3-29 h3-28 h3-27;
    }
}
```

Client opens connection to NGINX successfully and then NGINX trying to open TCP connection to upstream server. The server is available (172.20.0.3), I can see it in tcpdump. 172.20.0.2 is ip of NGINX in tcpdump. 172.20.0.1 is ip of Client in tcpdump.
Logs and tcpdump is attached below.

I expect that NGINX should be opened quic (udp+TLS1.3) connections to the server.

Comment: Did you get any solution or update? I'm stuck on the same issue. I was NGINX to Server to be also HTTP/3 (QUIC).